# Regex to get certains number of string - Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to get price of this strig "`Prix\xa0de base : 26 900 euros – bonus`" but there is a 0 in '`Prix\xa0de`' and I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
subject = "Prix\xa0de base : 26 900 euros – bonus"
match = re.search(r"^.*:\s+([\d ]+)\s+", subject)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
else:
    result = ""
```

result will be `26 900`

Comment: Thanks Theo, for the edition of my post and for the answer :)

Comment: @MarianaBelo My pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

If it always is followed by the word 'euros' then as simple as:

```
'(\d+ ?\d+) euros'
```

Capturing the number (or number with a space as separator) before 'euros'